# Are you aware of any lexical analyzer or lexer in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, full-text-search, lexical-analysis

Are you aware of any lexical analyzer or lexer in Qt? I need it for parsing text files.

Comment: What's in the text files? Is it code or natural language?

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/frameworks-technologies.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kinda interesting how Qt has evolved into an all-compassing framework that makes the programmer that uses it believe that anything that is useful has to start with the letter Q.  Very dot-netty.  Qt is just a class library that runs on top of the language, it doesn't preclude using everyday libraries that get a job done.  Especially when that's a library that has little to do with presenting a user interface, the job that Qt does so well.

There are many libraries that get lexical analysis and parsing done well.  That starts with Lex and Yacc, Flex and Bison next, etcetera.  You only have to Qt enable it for error messages, they readily support that.

Comment: The flip side of this is the same as it is for the .net guys: once you're using it, you might as well use all the bits because you have already assumed that your user has it installed. Makes sense to ask.

Comment: Qt also comes with a usable approach to Unicode, unlike standard C++. With that in mind, it's logical to look at Qt for textprocessing needs.

Comment: Not to mention that there is a Qt alternative  that replaces yacc/bison called QLALR (link: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Add_ons_Modules). So why would there not be a similar replacement for lexer?

Comment: Agree with the answer to use Flex or a similar tool. Not to mention there is an alternative to Flex called [RE/flex](https://sourceforge.net/projects/re-flex/). It's compatible with Flex and produces clean C++ code that integrates more seamlessly. There is also a lexer tool called [Quex](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quex/) that starts with a Q!!

Answer (score 2):

[`QXmlReader`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qxmlreader.html#setLexicalHandler) has allows you to define a lexical handler, for plain text you can use [`QRegExp`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qregexp.html).  If you want a full blown lexical analyzer take a look at [Quex](http://quex.sourceforge.net/) (not Qt specific, but is used to generate a C++ code based on your input).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use it... (it's quite complex if you ask me!) there is the Spirit library from boost.

This can be used "dynamically" in the sense that it does not generate other files that you have to then compile to run your parser.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex.html

But it's complex (to my point of view) since even just the #include don't always work right (if you include them in the wrong order or the documentation may not match the tutorial, I'm not too sure.) Yet, I see many people using it!